# Reusing the same reducer & epic for multiple Ajax calls like an api factory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

is using the same reducer to update different parts of state an anti pattern?

Like my data reducer has a `GET_DATA_DONE` action, updates state.data and then in another instance you use fetch something else and call `GET_DATA_DONE` to update `state.somethingElse`?

Or would you do something like `GET_SOMETHING_DATA_DONE` & so on.. multiple diff actions doing the same thing? (Hardly `DRY`)

reducers.js

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.GET_DATA_REQUESTED:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case actions.GET_DATA_DONE:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, data: action.payload };
    case actions.GET_DATA_FAILED:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

actions.js

```
export function getDataRequested() {
  return {
    type: 'GET_DATA_REQUESTED'
  };
}

export function getDataDone(data) {
  return {
    type: 'GET_DATA_DONE',
    payload: data
  };
}

export function getDataFailed(error) {
  return {
    type: 'GET_DATA_FAILED',
    payload: error
  };
};

export function getDataEpic(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(GET_DATA_REQUESTED)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(action.url)
        .map(response => getDataDone(response))
        .catch(error => getDataFailed(error))
    );
}
```

What't the best way to structure the app such that , `getDataEpic` acts like a api factory and the data returned from `getDataDone(response)` can be passed to another reducer to update a part of state based on the action, for example a cities action using `getDataDone` reducer dispatches another action which updates state.cities with the response?

Edit: I've made an app with rx-observable & redux calling 3 different api's but I ended up with a lot of duplicate code and just not happy with the solution, so i want to build a properly architectured app

Hope I was clear enough.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: IMO, don't have your reducers dispatching actions, do it all in your action creators layer before you hit your reducers, and have your reducers be as pure as possible in just setting your apps state. If you are returning the same information to be placed in the same part of the state to your reducers then there is no problem using the same reducer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @ajmamajma, trying to understand it, I should add more conditional logic to getDataDone func? or add more logic to the reducer? so that it can fire a different reducer based on what type of data is returned (for example checks if action.payload.cities exists: updates state.cities else falls through)

Comment: Yeah if you want to do conditionals, keep them in your actions and services (not the reducers). that being said it's totally fine to check if action.data has a node (or not) in the reducers and update based on that. So a little of both I guess. IMO - it's best to do all the computing in the actions, so something like you said, adding more logic to getDataDone would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's an anti-pattern if deals with state of it's own children, but if used too much, it could certainly get you in trouble. Having it modify totally unrelated state is a definite anti-pattern. [According to the docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/SplittingReducerLogic.html) the first line hits the nail on the head.

> For any meaningful application, putting all your update logic into a single reducer function is quickly going to become unmaintainable.

**We're not talking about 'all our data' but we are talking about all the data from a single API call.**

It's not too complicated in regards to setting a loading flag but in a real world app would get significantly more complicated for a reducer that is both setting a loading flag, error flag and 'data'. And that is assuming we even know what the data being requested is.

In your example, if the intention is to create an API factory through reducers, we have to assume an API could return any number of different data structures, right now it could be a `string` or an `int` but what if it's a deeply nested `Object`? How would you access this data and differentiate it between another piece of data?

---

**Let's say we have an app with this data structure for just the errors:**

```
{
  "errors": {
    "byId": {
      "1": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "There was an internal server error"
      },
      "2": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "There was another error."
      },
      "3": {
        "code": 999,
        "message": "Wow! weird error."
      },
    },
    "all": ["1", "2", "3"]
  }
}
```

I might have a byId reducer that returns a computed key with another reducer as the value.

```
byId = (state={}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_ERROR') {
    ...state,
    [action.id]:error_reducer(state[action.id], action)
  } else {
    return state
  }
}
```

error_reducer might look like

```
errorReducer = (state={}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_ERROR') {
    code: action.code,
    message: action.message
  } else {
    return state
  }
}
```

I think it makes more sense to have errorReducer handle both code and message because we know that they are both mutually inclusive pieces of data where as each error is mutually exclusive (different ids) and so require their own reducer.

**Another major advantage of this** when dealing with real-world applications is that when the data is separated one action can update state across **MANY** different areas of our app. When reducers handle multiple pieces of state these pieces of tied state become harder to update.

---

There are many different patterns you can employ with your reducers and none of them are wrong however I have found this pattern to work very well for me and i've used it successfully in a quite complex production app.

Having said all that, one possible approach for your AJAX function is to write a generic action that accepts an object that contains your dispatches.

By using a library like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) you can execute multiple dispatches to update different parts of your state with different pieces of data. I won't explain redux-thunk here as I think it's beyond the scope of the question.

an example object might look like this:

```
{
  getDataRequested: function () {
    return {
      type: 'GET_DATA_REQUESTED'
    };
  },
  getDataFailed: function (error) {
    return {
      type: 'GET_DATA_FAILED',
      payload: error
    };
  },
  getDataDone: function (data) {
    return {
      type: 'GET_DATA_DONE',
      payload: data
    };
  }
}
```

then you can pass this object of callbacks to your main AJAX function along with your API endpoint, REST request type etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation Matthew! Though I saw it quite late but definitely still helpful! : )